# What is the most natural way (or differences) to ask if someone wants to do something?

Tags: conjugations, questions

(Using the verb "飲む" as an example)

- 飲みたいですか？
- 飲みたくないですか？
- 飲むことが欲しいですか？

What are the differences between these forms? Also, is there a more natural way to ask if someone wants to do something?

Comment: Generally, you don't directly ask someone what they "want".  It can feel rude or intrusive.  You can ask, 飲みませんか

Comment: @A.Ellett Hm, I get it, but what if I'm talking to a friend, I would say "飲まないの"?

Comment: 「飲まないの？」sounds like "You don't want to drink that? Why?" 「コーラ飲まない？」is better.

Comment: @EddieKal Oh, I understand

Comment: Are you really asking if they "want" to do something?  Or does "want" here mean you're inviting them to do something together?

Comment: @istrasci I didn't realize that there is such a difference. Could you tell me how it would look in each case? For example: "Do you want to drink?" when a waiter asks and when a friend invites you to drink (I don't know if this is a good example. If not, you can use another example)